# Mule flow trigger another flow

Tags: mule, mule-flow

I have 2 data sources I am building an integration for.  I have a workflow that needs to do the following in this exact order:

1. Get records from datasource1
2. Post records into datasource2
3. Get newly created record in datasource2
4. Update records in datasource1 with id field from datasource2

I have to use 2 flow's because I have 2 inbound data points (step 1 and 3 above).  However both step 1 and 3 are firing at the same time, which causes problems.

Here is my question: Is there a way for me to trigger the flow for step 3 at the end of the previous flow?  Or does anyone have a suggestion for handling this differently?

Comment: By datasource do you mean JDBC polling inbound endpoint?

Comment: No, sorry I wasn't more specific, they are http inbound endpoints.  The Post and Update are http outbound endpoints.

Comment: I don't get how step 3 can happen at the same time as step 1 since it takes step 2 to fire, as if I understand your question well it seems step 2 is an outbound HTTP endpoint that calls an inbound HTTP endpoint at step 3. Maybe show your XML config so we can better understand.